# Python "socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed" caused by socket.connect()

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming, udp, pyqt6

I'm trying to send and receive binary data using UDP protocol over an Ethernet connection using sockets in Python.

I managed to do this using a standalone script and tested it by connecting two laptops using an Ethernet cable and using the Hercules software on the other laptop to send/receive data.

However, when trying to do this in a PyQt6 based GUI app, I get the following error:

```
line 33, in __init__
    self.sock.connect((self.sendToAddress, self.sendToPort))
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

My main functions are:

```py
def __init__(self, addr, port):

    self.sock = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET,type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
    
    self.data = None
    self.sendToAddress = str(addr)
    self.sendToPort = int(port)
    self.reply_data = None
    self.replyBufSize = 1024

    
    self.sock.bind(('169.234.29.200', 8000)) 
   
    self.sock.connect((self.sendToAddress, self.sendToPort)) # error caused by this line

def sendData(self):

    if(isinstance(self.data, bytes) == False):
        self.data = self.data.encode()

   
    bytes_Sent = self.sock.sendto(self.data, (self.sendToAddress, self.sendToPort))
    print("sent data = ", self.data)
    print("bytesSent = ", bytes_Sent)

def getData(self):
        
    while self.reply_data is None:
        print("waiting for msg")
        self.reply_data = self.sock.recvfrom(self.replyBufSize)
        
        print("still waiting")

    print(self.reply_data)`
```

The code for sending and receiving is identical in the standalone script and in the PyQt6 app, but it works in the standalone and fails here.

I've looked this up extensively online, and almost all the solutions involve a missing `socket.connect()` statement. However, in my case, the `socket.connect()` seems to be causing it.

I've also tried flushing my DNS, and restarting the PC.

Please let me know what the issue is, and how to fix it.

**UPDATE:**
I was taking the sendToAddress and sendToPort as inputs from the user, storing them in a file which acts as shared memory and reading them when the socket needs to be created.
However, if I hardcode the values then it works with no problems.

Could there be any specific reason why taking the values as input causes the error?

I used `print(socketObj.getsockname())` to verify that the socket object is properly the created. The error still occurs at the connect() statement.

Comment: The issue is likely that the hostname you're using (`self.sendToAddress`) cannot be resolved to an IP address. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68654742/1076479

Comment: Error 11001 is [`WSAHOST_NOT_FOUND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2): "No such host is known. The name is not an official host name or alias, or it cannot be found in the database(s) being queried. This error may also be returned for protocol and service queries, and means that the specified name could not be found in the relevant database."

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! Simply put, by going to `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections` and changing the `Ethernet Adapter` settings, I put the proper IP Addresses that the application was using.
Hope this helps anyone facing the same problem!